# Angular child routes route params

Tags: angular, routes

I have a url such as http://localhost:4200/analyse/portugal/lisbon/demography/2022 I create route paths but I got error. Where is my mistake?

> main.ts:6 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot
> match any routes. URL Segment:
> 'analyse/portugal/lisbon/demography/2022' Error: NG04002: Cannot match
> any routes. URL Segment: 'analyse/portugal/lisbon/demography/2022

```
{
    path: 'analyse', component: AnalyseComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
        {
            path: 'portugal/:province/demography', component: DemographyComponent, children: [
                {path: '', redirectTo: 'population', pathMatch: 'full'},
                {path: 'population/:year', component: PopulationComponent},
                {path: 'age/:year', component: AgeComponent},
            ]
        },
}
```

Comment: No route matches "analyse/portugal/lisbon/demography/2022", check the innermost route. You need to have either "population" or "age" before ":year". Otherwise, you need to create a route with just ":year".

Comment: http://localhost:4200/analyse/portugal/lisbon/demography/2022 What should I do for a link like this? I want the year to be at the end.

Comment: Add `{path: ':year', component: /* Your Component */}` within the same (route) level as  'age/:year' route.

Comment: I have already defined {path: 'population/:year', component: PopulationComponent} like this.  { path: 'population', component: PopulationComponent, children: [{path: ':year', component: PopulationComponent}]} do you say like this?

Comment: But in this case, your URL should be "analyse/portugal/lisbon/demography/population/2022"

Comment: Yes I want to use "analyse/portugal/lisbon/demography/population/2022" like this but I got same error.

Comment: Would be great if you can share the latest code for your routing. Thanks.

Comment: İt was my mistake I used wrong url "analyse/portugal/lisbon/demography/population/2022" like this is working I have forgetten to write population after demography thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    path: 'analyse', component: AnalyseComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
    {
        path: 'portugal/:province/demography', component: DemographyComponent, children: [
            {path: '', redirectTo: 'population', pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path: 'population/:year', component: PopulationComponent},
            {path: 'age/:year', component: AgeComponent},
        ]
    },
}

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log("province", params);
    });
    this.route?.parent?.params?.subscribe((params) => {
        console.log("year", params);
    })
```

The url will be work like this "http://localhost:4200/analyse/portugal/lisbon/demography/population/2022" Here another problem is cannot get two params directly. Is there a solution?

Comment: If you have question, please create another question post for it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "b",
    children: [
      {
        path: "users/:id",
        children: [
          {
            path: "edit",
            children: [
              {
                path: "village",
                children: [
                  {
                    path: "store",
                    children: [
                      {
                        path: "edit/:id",
                        component: HelloComponent
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

```js
this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
  console.log('childPraram', params);
});

this.router?.parent?.params?.subscribe((params) => {
  console.log('parentParam', params);
});
```

```js
this.router.navigate([`/b/users/1/edit/village/store/edit/GameStore`]);
```

try it

Comment: I want to use one subscription. You used two subscriptions.

Comment: don't see how the subscriptions are relevant tot the original question here. they are just here to prove that to top part works. If you want to merge subscriptions you can use combineLatest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).